# Cassandra Db insertion issue Via springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

Am trying to insert values into my Cassandra database but am getting this error. Referred to data type mapping here everything seems to be ok... http://itdoc.hitachi.co.jp/manuals/3020/30203V0300e/BV030040.HTM

> reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented:
> com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.type.codec.CodecNotFoundException:
> Codec not found for requested operation: [UUID <-> java.lang.String]
> Caused by:
> com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.type.codec.CodecNotFoundException:
> Codec not found for requested operation: [UUID <-> java.lang.String]

Here is the entity object

```
package com.sams.pricing.prism.data.processor.entity;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import lombok.*;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.PrimaryKeyType;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.Column;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.PrimaryKeyColumn;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.Table;

import java.sql.Timestamp;

//import java.time.Instant;

@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Table(value = "retail_lifecycle")
@EntityScan
@ToString
public class PricingLifeCycleEntity {

  @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "itemnbr", ordinal = 0, type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
  private Integer itemNbr;

  @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "clubnbr", ordinal = 1, type = PrimaryKeyType.CLUSTERED)
  private Short locationNbr;

  @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "price", ordinal = 2, type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
  private Double price;

  @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "pricestartts", ordinal = 3, type = PrimaryKeyType.CLUSTERED)
  private Timestamp priceStartTs;

  @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "status", ordinal = 4, type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
  private String status;

  @Column(value = "createts")
  private Timestamp createTs;

  @Column(value = "currency")
  private String currency;
  
  @Column(value = "lastupdatets")
  private Timestamp lastUpdateTs;
  
  @Column(value = "priceendts")
  private Timestamp priceEndTs;
  
  @Column(value = "pricereasoncode")
  private String priceReasonCode;
  
  @Column(value = "pricereasoncodedesc")
  private String priceReasonCodeDesc;
  
  @Column(value = "pricetype")
  private String priceType;
  
  @Column(value = "pricetypedesc")
  private String priceTypeDesc;
   
  @Column(value = "statusdesc")
  private String statusDesc;
  
  @Column(value = "submissionclient")
  private String submissionClient;

  @Column(value = "submissionts")
  private Timestamp submissionTs;

  @Column(value = "submissionuserid")
  private String submissionUserId;
  
  @Column(value = "uniqueid")
  private String uniqueId;
 
}
```

Here is the database

```
CREATE TABLE cassandra.prism.retail_lifecycle (
    itemnbr INTEGER NOT NULL,
    clubnbr SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    price DOUBLE NOT NULL,
    pricestartts TYPE_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    status VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    createts TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
    currency VARCHAR,
    lastupdatets TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
    priceendts TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
    pricereasoncode VARCHAR,
    pricereasoncodedesc VARCHAR,
    pricetype VARCHAR,
    pricetypedesc VARCHAR,
    statusdesc VARCHAR,
    submissionclient VARCHAR,
    submissionts TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
    submissionuserid VARCHAR,
    uniqueid VARCHAR,
    CONSTRAINT RETAIL_LIFECYCLE_PK PRIMARY KEY (itemnbr,clubnbr,price,pricestartts,status)
```

and here is the test case

```
@Test
  public void test2() throws Exception {
    MockEndpoint mock =
        camelContext.getEndpoint("mock:" + Endpoints.SEDA_PROCESS_ENDPOINT, MockEndpoint.class);

    AdviceWith.adviceWith(
        camelContext,
        Endpoints.SEDA_SEND_ENDPOINT,
        // intercepting an exchange on route
        r -> {
          // replacing consumer with direct component
          r.replaceFromWith(Endpoints.SEDA_SEND_ENDPOINT);
          // mocking producer
          r.mockEndpoints("seda*");

          // weaving a last step to your route that will redirect the message to mock:result
          r.weaveAddLast().to(mock);
        });
    
    var eventId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    
    System.out.println("hereeeee "+eventId );
    String message = "{\"itemNbr\":8831,\"locationNbr\":4707,\"price\":55.0,\"priceStartTs\":\"2022-11-11T03:24:14.749Z\",\"status\":\"SUCCESS\",\"createTs\":\"2022-11-11T03:24:14.749Z\",\"currency\":\"USD\",\"lastUpdateTs\":\"2022-11-11T03:24:14.749Z\",\"priceEndTs\":\"2022-11-11T03:24:14.749Z\",\"priceReasonCode\":\"TEST\",\"priceReasonCodeDesc\":\"TEST\",\"priceType\":\"TST\",\"priceTypeDesc\":\"TST\",\"statusDesc\":\"TST\",\"submissionClient\":\"TST\",\"submissionTs\":\"2022-11-11T03:24:14.749Z\",\"submissionUserId\":\"TST\",\"uniqueId\":\"121212111212112121212121\"}";


    // setting expectations
    mock.expectedMessageCount(1);

    Map<String, Object> headers = new HashMap<>();
    headers.put(PrismConstants.APP_NAME, PrismConstants.PRICING_LIFE_CYCLE_APP_NAME);
    headers.put(PrismConstants.EVENT_ID, UUID.randomUUID().toString());

    // invoking consumer
    // we are going to send as a Json body object
    producerTemplate.sendBodyAndHeaders(
        Endpoints.SEDA_SEND_ENDPOINT,
        message,
        headers);

    // asserting mock is satisfied
    mock.assertIsSatisfied();
    var result = mock.getExchanges().get(0).getIn();
    System.out.println(result.getBody().toString());
  }
```

Edit - DB info and schema update

Primary Key entity class

```
package com.sams.pricing.prism.data.processor.entity;

import lombok.*;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.PrimaryKeyType;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.PrimaryKeyClass;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.PrimaryKeyColumn;

import java.sql.Timestamp;

@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@PrimaryKeyClass
@ToString
public class PricingLifeCyclePrimaryKey {

    @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "itemnbr", ordinal = 0, type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
    private Integer itemNumber;

    @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "clubnbr", ordinal = 1, type = PrimaryKeyType.CLUSTERED)
    private Short locationNumber;

    @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "price", ordinal = 2, type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
    private Double price;

    @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "pricestartts", ordinal = 3, type = PrimaryKeyType.CLUSTERED)
    private Timestamp pricestartTs;

    @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "status", ordinal = 4, type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
    private String status;


}
```

Schema code for primary key

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you please add the spring-data code, you share a camel route which is not related to Spring. Also the table you share is not the same as the bean. In the table the Partitioned key is `itemnbr` and everything else is clustering column `clubnbr,price,pricestartts,status`. As composite primaary key you will need a dedicated PrimaryKey Class probably.

Comment: Please share the real cassandra schema `uniqueid` is probably a UUID and not a varchar.

Comment: Have updated the question - I am not sure what you mean by spring data-code could you please elaborate

Comment: Have left an answer I manually inserted event It generated by the UUID into the string however now it is saying that the table does not exist please refer to the answer below

Answer (score 1):

Notice that:

- In your `test2` you are not using Cassandra what so ever, it would be valuable if you can add the associated code.
- The table schema is still unclear as you share screenshots of a JDBC tools maybe. The best would be to get the output of `describe table retail_lifecycle` using cqlsh to have the detailed schema.

**Error 1: CodecNotFoundException**

```
reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: 
com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.type.codec.CodecNotFoundException: 
Codec not found for requested operation: [UUID <-> java.lang.String]...
```

This message means that in your Java Entity there is an attribute with invalid type:

- either the java field is as an `UUID` whereas the column in the databases was rather a `TEXT` or a `VARCHAR`.
- or the java field is as String and the expected column is an UUID.

**Error 2: InvalidQueryException**

```
table retail_lifecycle does not exist; nested exception is com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.servererrors.InvalidQueryException: table retail_lifecycle does not exist
```

This message tells you that the table your want to write does not exist. Either the table `retail_lifecycle` does not exist at all or you may have not provide a keyspace in the `CqlSession` definition.

Comment: Error 1 is resolved and I have uploaded a screenshot of the create table code - I hope that is sufficient, Will work on getting the associated Cassandra code

Comment: Resolved issue - looks like the cassandra Keyspace was not properly picking up the correct name

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by manually sending in an event ID but now getting this error - looked like it was a type mismatch.

> reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented:
> org.springframework.data.cassandra.CassandraInvalidQueryException:
> ReactivePreparedStatementCallback; CQL [INSERT INTO retail_lifecycle
> (itemnbr,price,status,clubnbr,pricestartts,createts,currency,lastupdatets,priceendts,pricereasoncode,pricereasoncodedesc,pricetype,pricetypedesc,statusdesc,submissionclient,submissionts,submissionuserid,uniqueid)
> VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)]; table retail_lifecycle
> does not exist; nested exception is
> com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.servererrors.InvalidQueryException:
> table retail_lifecycle does not exist Caused by:
> org.springframework.data.cassandra.CassandraInvalidQueryException:
> ReactivePreparedStatementCallback; CQL [INSERT INTO retail_lifecycle
> (itemnbr,price,status,clubnbr,pricestartts,createts,currency,lastupdatets,priceendts,pricereasoncode,pricereasoncodedesc,pricetype,pricetypedesc,statusdesc,submissionclient,submissionts,submissionuserid,uniqueid)
> VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)]; table retail_lifecycle
> does not exist; nested exception is
> com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.servererrors.InvalidQueryException:
> table retail_lifecycle does not exist